# rails render partial with ajax (on load-- NOT after request)

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I must be overlooking something here. Any help would be appreciated.

I want to load a partial on a page with ajax when I visit a page. ONLY on visit, not after a request is being made. So in other words, I visit the page, all HTML displays instantly, and then a section of the page loads the data with ajax into the partial and it's displayed.

When I load my index view it loads the page, but it doesn't load the partial. I get this error in console:

```
Unexpected identifier 'sites'. Expected ')' to end a argument list
```

**index.html.erb - for Site.rb**

```
<h1>Listing sites</h1>

<div id="sites-container">

</div>

<%= link_to 'New Site', new_site_path %>
```

**_online_status.html.erb - partial**

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Location</th>
      <th>IP Address</th>
      <th colspan="3"></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <% @sites.each do |site| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= site.name %></td>
        <td><%= site.ip %> <%= online_status(site.ip) %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Show', site %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_site_path(site) %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', site, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

**sites_helper.html.erb**

```
def online_status(ip)
  ping_count = 2
  result = `ping -q -c #{ping_count} #{ip_address}`

  if $?.exitstatus == 0
    return "Online"
  else
    return "Unreachable"
  end
end
```

**application.js**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#sites-container").replaceWith('<%= escape_javascript(render 'sites/online_status') %>');
});
```

Comment: anybody have any more ideas? I'm really clueless here.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#sites-container").replaceWith('<%= j render "sites/online_status" %>');
});
```

Comment: thanks for reply, but this produces same javascript error in console log

Comment: OH is online_status a partial? You might have to specify render partial: "sites/online_status", my bad.

Comment: I changed to `$("#sites-container").replaceWith('<%= j render partial: 'sites/online_status' %>');` and even still.. same error. it doesn't seem to be able to find the correct path

Comment: Make sure you dont use single quotes on 'sites/online_status' but double quotes like "sites/online_status"! It's important in that context!

Comment: Hmmm. When I changed to `"sites/online_status"` it renders this in my view now on the page "<%= j render partial: "sites/_online_status" %>"